# User inactive report. List all users who have been inactive for the last month. SQL server

Tags: sql-server

I was asked to create an sql stored procedure for this problem in one of my previous assignments.

Given only these two tables:
UserRole(RoleID,RoleName,IsDefault)
dbo.User(UserID, UserName, UserPassword, RoleID)

How do I list all inactive users for the last month... without having an login date field ?

[image: The Tables]

Comment: have you tried something?, are you getting an error?

Comment: I have tried using sys built in functions but nothing there seems to be helping.

Comment: I have tried code like :                                                               
SELECT [dbo].[User].*, STATS_DATE(OBJECT_ID,stats_id) AS statistics_update_date
FROM [dbo].[User], sys.stats
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('User.UserID');

Comment: It seems like there's no way for you to get the info you've been asked for

Comment: @James00 This is just User and Role table.  How do you expect to get inactive users without additional tables???

Comment: How do you propose you do this without a login date? Without having the data, somewhere, you can't query said data. You wouldn't be able to write a query to return all customers in a table who's favourite colour is blue if you don't record their favourite colour. The same is true here; if you don't store a login time, you can't return data based on their (last) login date.

Comment: On a different note, that table diagram implies you're storing the password as a raw or encrypted value; this is generally a bad idea. You should, ideally, be using a password hash and salt.

Comment: Thank you for the replies. Obviously I agree with everything hence me asking but this question problem was in an assignment and I am curious to know how its possible.

Comment: The tables were given to us. Can't change them.

Comment: If an example "Role" could be "InActive" you could query which were InActive.  However, you have absolutely no date info, so answer the whole question of "InActive for the last month" is not possible.  Either the original question's answer was "not enough data provided" or the original question is incomplete, or the posted question is incomplete.